# IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username　の意味

Tags: python

現在、djangoでアプリ開発を勉強している大学生です。開発環境はvisual stdio codeを用いています。
アプリ開発をしている最中に、

> IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

というエラーが出たのですが、これは一体どういう意味なのでしょうか？
まだまだプログラミングを学び始めたばかりなので、専門用語がまだ理解しきれていないこともあり、何をしていいか分かりません。
プロフェッショナルの皆様に力をお貸しして頂けるとありがたいです。

Comment: この辺の記事で登録済みユーザーを再度登録しようとしたか、モデルにユーザー名が無いのでデフォルト名が適用され、それで多重登録になったとかの事象があるようです。[StackOverflow記事1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53907647/9014308), [同記事2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47327406/9014308), [同記事3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42095401/9014308), [Google記事](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/C8Q7CTpcChc), [django-allauth記事1](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1014), [同記事2](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1152)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

auth_user テーブルのusernameカラムは同じ値を複数もてません。というエラーです。
DjangoやPythonではなく、データベースからそのようなエラーが返されている状況です。登録済みのusernameと同じ値でユーザー追加しようとしたのではないでしょうか？

エラー文面は「ユニーク制約の整合性エラー」です。この用語で調べてみてください。